# Trying to calculate distance between points from a .txt file

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, coordinates, gis

I am trying to figure out how to calculate the length of a line segment using coordinates that are in a text file:

> X,Y format (x,y,x,y,x,y,etc...)
>
> 4.5,10.0,4.5,5.7,5.5,2.5,6.5,0.3,6.8,0.0,1.0,1.0,3.5,3.5,2,5,6.0,2.0

This is what I have so far:

> Python

```
   # -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
#Starter code for GIS301 Lab 2
#GIS301Lab2Starter.py

import math

#-----------------------------------------------------------
#Procedure for reading a coordinate text file
#in x1,y1,x2,y2,… xn,yn format
#and resulting in a list as type float

#open file to read
file = open(r'C:\Users\Tristan\Desktop\USB_Backup_10-4-16\2016-2017\Fall2016\SpatialDataStructures\Labs\Lab2\points.txt','r')

#read file to string
coordString = file.read()
#Split coordString into list elements
coordList = coordString.split(',')
#convert from string to float type
for index, item in enumerate(coordList):
    coordList[index] = float(coordList[index])
file.close
#-----------------------------------------------------------
print (coordList)    
#add more code here
numPoints = len(coordList)/2
print("Number of Points")
print (numPoints)


x = [float(r) for r in coordList[0::2]]
y = [float(r) for r in coordList[1::2]]

xy = list(zip(x,y))


# pre-define distance and add subsequent distances
dist = 0
for r in coordList(len(xy)-1):
    dist += ( (xy[r][0]-xy[r+1][0])**2 + (xy[r][1]-xy[r+1][1])**2 )**0.5

print (dist)



#for r in coordList(len(xy)-1):
#    dist += ( (xy[r][0]-xy[r+1][0])**2 + (xy[r][1]-xy[r+1][1])**2 )**0.5
```

> When I run it in PyhthonWin:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tristan\Desktop\USB_Backup_10-4-16\2016-2017\Fall2016\SpatialDataStructures\Labs\Lab2\GOERSLab2.py", line 39, in <module>
    for r in coordList(len(xy)-1):
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

The equation for calculating distance between two points is:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOcu0.png

Then I need to add them all up!

Comment: Where is the error coming from, what line ?

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of `coordList = [float(coordList) for coordList in coordString.replace(',', '')]`. In fact, simply removing that line appears to leave you with a list in exactly the format you wanted anyway. It's a strange operation as written; you'd want something like `coordList = [float(item) for item in coordList]`. But as I said, it's redundant

Comment: What you're doing essentially boils down to `['float(a_list) for a_list in string_with_no_separators]`.... which doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

From what you have provided I do not see the need to over complicate this.  Assuming you can properly import your text-file data, and split it, you could do this:

```
points = ['4.5','10.0','4.5','5.7','5.5','2.5','6.5','0.3','6.8','0.0','1.0','1.0','3.5','3.5','2','5','6.0','2.0']


x = [float(r) for r in points[0::2]]
y = [float(r) for r in points[1::2]]

# put x/y coordinates in tuples
xy = list(zip(x,y))

# pre-define distance and add subsequent distances
dist = 0
for r in xrange(len(xy)-1):
    dist += ( (xy[r][0]-xy[r+1][0])**2 + (xy[r][1]-xy[r+1][1])**2 )**0.5
```

I think something along these lines will work well (you don't even need to put the coordinates in tuples, really).  Is this along the lines of what you needed?

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I think it is what I am looking for. However I am running into a problem:
--------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tristan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 326, in RunScript
    exec(codeObject, __main__.__dict__)
  File "D:\2016-2017\Fall2016\SpatialDataStructures\Labs\Lab2\GOERSLab2.py", line 38, in <module>
    for r in coordList(len(xy)-1):
TypeError: object of type 'zip' has no len()

Comment: You must be using Python 3.x, that makes a difference.  Convert xy to a list as shown above in my edited answer.

Comment: That is giving me a -- TypeError: 'list' object is not callable -- error when I put -- list(zip(x,y)) -- Does it have something to do with what x and y equals?

Comment: This works on my machine, so the problem is likely in your preceding code.  Can you update your post with your current code?

Comment: @Tristan try `list(zip(x,y))` (with a comma)

Comment: I updated the code with the comma. You can see the error that I get above -- TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: I think that I found the problem. ----

for r in coordList(len(xy)-1): is supposed to be for r in range(len(xy)-1):

Comment: Excellent.  If this has been helpful, please feel free to mark this as the accepted answer.